How to Remove Data from two different collections in one query
How can I remove data from two different collections in ArangoDB via one query?
(Data in collection #1 has no link to data in collection #2)
Thank you

let collAItem = (
FOR item IN collA
  RETURN item   )


let collBItem = (
FOR item IN collB
  RETURN item   )
 

  REMOVE collAItem in collA 
  REMOVE collBItem in collB


You can remove an item in loop query
let collAItem = (
FOR item IN collA
  REMOVE item IN collA
  RETURN OLD   )


let collBItem = (
FOR item IN collB
  REMOVE item IN collB
  RETURN OLD   )
 

RETURN {collAItem, collBItem}

